# Error message cannot use URL in swift 3 swift file

Tags: xcode

I created a  swift file using a class called Course . Everything works in my code except when I try to input the URL. I get an error Message.
Here's is my sample code

```
URL(String:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBULK-w-i90")!
```

I keep getting error

> Argument labels '(String)' do not match any available overloads

I'm not sure what that means and how can I fix this problem . 
here is the code written out I follow video but keep getting errors.

```
import UIKit

class CourseStore
{ 

    class func downloadNewCourses()-> [Course] 
    { 
        var courses = [Course]() 

        let chefCourse = Course(buttonImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cover_chef"), 
                                title: "Become a Pro Chef", 
                                instructor: "Gordon Ramsay", 
                                featuredImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chef"), 
                                introductionVideoUrl: URL(String:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBULK-w-i90")!, 
                                introductionVideoUrl: , 
                                description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda." 
        ) 
        return courses 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Creat seperated file using a struct

Comment: What's your `Course` `init` used? Probably it's using `NSURL`

Comment: Please format your question. It's totally unreadable

Comment: There is twice ` introductionVideoUrl:` and the second one with no param?

Comment: Typo. Swift is case sensitive: `URL(String` vs. `URL(string`. Please read the  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url)

Comment: PS: I edited the question. You will see the syntax error at once.

Comment: Thanks I think it's because i used upper case String the case is sensitive is the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Argument labels '(String)' do not match any available overloads

Means that `URL` doesn't have constructor which has those parameters. In your case you named parameter `String` but it should be lowercased `string`.

**Instead use**

```
URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBULK-w-i90")!
```